Largest spacetime symmetry group possible for a relativistic field theory (without supersymmetry)?
By the Coleman-Mandula theorem, we know that the largest spacetime symmetry group massive fields can have is the Poincare group. On the other hand, massless fields can have a larger spacetime symmetry group, namely the conformal group. My question is this - is the conformal group the largest possible spacetime symmetry group massless fields can have? Or can they have a larger spacetime symmetry group?
Note: I'm aware that one way to expand this symmetry group is to add supersymmetry to our theory. I want to know if there's a way to extend this group without resorting to supersymmetry, or is the conformal group as large as we can go.

If the theory is free or 2d then the conformal group can be extended just like the Poincare group can be extended in the massive case.
If not though, you cannot extend the spacetime symmetry without supercharges.
More detail
Since Coleman and Mandula proved their theorem by analyzing the S-matrix, it should be clear that they were focusing on interacting theories. They also demanded analyticity in the scattering angle which is where $d > 2$ comes from. Only a bad source would review the Coleman-Manduala theorem without mentioning this. The good source I used to learn it was the introduction of Argyres' SUSY notes.
For free theories, the point is that you can build combinations of $\partial_{\mu_1} \dots \partial_{\mu_m} \phi$ and $\partial_{\nu_1} \dots \partial_{\nu_n} \phi$ which have vanishing divergence due to $\Box \phi = 0$. The number of uncontracted indices can be as large as you want leading to infinitely many conserved currents. A search term for this is "higher spin algebra". For 1 + 1d, the point is that the set of outgoing momenta $\{ p'_1, \dots, p'_n \}$ can be taken to equal the set of incoming momenta $\{ p_1, \dots p_n \}$. I.e. all you do is permute the elements. This is non-trivial scattering which cannot be forbidden by a conservation law. A search term for this is "itnegrable field theory".
If you want to extend the generators of the conformal group without a higher-spin current, you would need to have a current with spin-1 which is not internal or a current of spin-2 which is not a decoupled stress tensor. For this, it will be good to follow the logic of Simmons-Duffin's notes where the properties of the conformal group (and not some other group) are shown to follow inevitably from the assumption of a spin-2 traceless conserved current.

A couple of follow-up questions -


Could you provide some references on how to extend the Poincare group for free or 2d theories? I did not know this could be done.


In the paper you linked, the authors assumed the existence of a conserved current of spin s > 2. Does extending the conformal group automatically imply the existence of such a current? If so, could you provide some references on how this happens?


